# How to detect a browser that will not support XHR2 Upload progress

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Few android browsers including Samsung default browsers on older devices will not support

```
xhr.upload.onprogress
```

Event. So we cannot show realtime  upload progress on that browsers.

How can I detect those browsers?
So I can change my setup to show progress.

Comment: You could read the browsers headers. Although personally I think it would be better just doing `if(typeof xhr.upload.onprogress === 'undefined')` (or similar). This way you avoid checking against every browser.

Comment: @EricMartinez getting "Object" on both level1 and level2 browsers.

Comment: sorry, getting "null" on both level1 and level2 browsers.

Comment: try `XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.prototype.hasOwnProperty('onprogress')` or http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/how-to-detect-if-the-new-html5-file-upload-progress-information-is-available-in-your-browser

Comment: @befzz getting true on lavel 2 but not output on level 1 (try to alert) no debugging setup

Comment: `if(XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.prototype.hasOwnProperty('onprogress')){alert("level 2")}else{alert("level 1")};`  Only Worked on level 2  @befzz

Comment: maybe `XMLHttpRequestEventTarget` even not exists on `level 1`? window.ProgressEvent? google have some what u can test ;)

Comment: @befzz in general onprogress will support on both (level 1 and level 2) for download. but on level 1 onprogress will not work for upload.

Comment: on level 1 its also works, but not in early versions http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20121206/#dom-xmlhttprequest-send so.. if `upload.onprogress` exists thats hard to detect if it will work or not D:  may be by navigator version... i feel: solution exists but... how? :D Workaround - makes small pre-request to detect it. Need to find old browser for testing. later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply :

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
if ( xhr && ('upload' in xhr) && ('onprogress' in xhr.upload) ) // attach event...
```

So if you want a function :

```
function supportAjaxUploadProgressEvents() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  return !! (xhr && ('upload' in xhr) && ('onprogress' in xhr.upload));
}
```

Comment: Please test your code and post full code if possible.

Comment: Your code works perfectly!

function supportAjaxUploadProgressEvents() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  return !! (xhr && ('upload' in xhr) && ('onprogress' in xhr.upload));
}
if(!supportAjaxUploadProgressEvents()){
alert("I never support xhr2");
}else{
 alert("I support xhr2");
}

Answer (score 2):

hm. tested a very old Firefox's. 3.5.2.

first version that have `(new XMLHttpRequest).upload` property.

Current version Chrome:

```
send(1); //progress 1 of 1
send(40000000_chars); // 1,2 or more progress events.
```

Firefox 3.5.2:

```
send(1); //no progress events.
send(40000000_chars); // some progress events.
```

So if *browser **send**ing time* is not big, there is no `pregress` events on old browsers.

But `load` event with `.loaded == .total` is fired normally.

---

Current conclusion: data was send too fast for old browsers.

Comment: Yea for very small files there will be no progress event will executed. but for a large file eg: 20Mb file on 512K connection will take few minutes to complete upload process, still on level 1 browsers there will be Zero progress events.

Comment: @Vishnu can u run in level 1(one-line script): `alert("upload: " +('upload' in XMLHttpRequest.prototype) + " XHRET: " +(XMLHttpRequestEventTarget?true:false) + " PE: " + (ProgressEvent?true:false))`

Comment: Got True on level 2, but on Level Alert function is not executed or throw some error , don't know what's going on. how can we debug those browsers?

Answer (score 0):

The below was tested in FF 3.5.2 to return `false`, but for latest Chrome/FF/IE11 `true`

The exception is thrown on trying to read the `onpgress` after being set.

Hope that helps,

```javascript
  function isSupported() {
      var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
      try {
          xhr.upload.onprogress = isSupported;
          var x = xhr.upload.onprogress;
          return true;
      } catch(e) {
          return false;
      }
  }
```